# Extensions of $\mathbb{Z_3}$ by $\mathbb{Z_9}$

Tags: group-theory, homological-algebra, exact-sequence, group-cohomology

I'm working through MacLane's *Homological Algebra*, and I was trying to compute some easy examples of Ext groups, but just confused myself:

I'm trying to compute all three (I know there's three by the first theorem in the third chapter) extensions of $Z_9$ by $Z_3$.

If I resolve $Z_3$ and set it up, it looks like this:

$$\begin{matrix}
0 & \to & 3Z & \xrightarrow{i} & Z & \xrightarrow{\pi} & Z_3 & \to & 0 \\
\ & \   & \downarrow^{h^i} & \ & \downarrow^{\psi} \ & \ & \downarrow^{\simeq} \\
0 & \to & Z_9 & \xrightarrow{i'} & P & \xrightarrow{\pi'} & Z_3 & \to & 0
\end{matrix}$$

Now as he proves, the class of the extension we get by filling in the bottom given $h^i$ is a function of the homotopy class of $h^i$ (considered as a morphism of complexes lifting the identity on $Z_3$). To fill in the bottom (can't figure out how to make $\psi, i', \pi'$ dashed). We compute the pushout of the left square.

Ok, so starting with $h^0 = 0$, it's easy to see that I just get the split extension as expected.

Then taking $h^1(3n) = n \text{ mod } 9$, I get $Z_{27}$, no problem. Next I choose $h^2(3n) = 3n \text{ mod } 9$. Then to compute the pushout $P \simeq \frac{Z_9 \bigoplus Z}{N}$ for $N = \{ (-3n \text{ mod } 9, 3n) : 3n \in 3Z \}$.

So after starting at this for a day or two, I believe this is metacycic? Anyways, this group of order 27 is something like (here's where I get v. confused):  $P = \langle a,b \mid 3a = 3b, 9a = 9b = 0, b^{-1} a b = a\rangle$.

But looking at grouppros groups of order 27, the semidirect product I think this should be (https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/M27) doesn't have these relations (or atleast it's not obvious how to change basis), and moreover isn't abelian. What's going on? What is the third isomorphism class of extensions here?

Thanks!

---

As I was told in the comments, there are only two abelian extensions of $Z_9$ by $Z_3$. I was going based on MacLane's Proposition 1.1 in Chapter 3, which says that for Abelian A, $\text{Ext}_Z(Z_m,A) \simeq A/mA$. Still not sure why I interpreted that wrong, but I'll update this when I figure that out.

Also, not sure why P as defined above isn't a group, but that's probably not too hard once I think about it in a less braindead state (thought it does seem to fit the description of metacyclics by presentations here https://mathworld.wolfram.com/MetacyclicGroup.html).

Comment: You cannot have the right definition of the extension, because you are essentially claiming that all soluble groups are abelian. Notice that $N$ and $G/N$ are abelian groups, your construction only produces abelian $G$. As a set your group is right, $Z_9\oplus Z$, but the group action is not the one inherited from this structure.

Comment: @DavidCraven: It appears from context that they are talking only about extensions of abelian groups, i.e. those that would be classified by $\operatorname{Ext}^1_{\mathbb{Z}}(\mathbb{Z}_3,\mathbb{Z}_9)$.

Comment: Yes, I was just trying to compute the extensions of $\mathbb{Z}$-modules here, seeing as that's giving me enough trouble.

Comment: So why would you expect to see the group M27 then? It's not a $\mathbb{Z}$-module. There are only two $\mathbb{Z}$-module extensions of $Z_3$ by $Z_9$.

Comment: Honestly, just because I was staring at it for so long I thought I got it and then started getting confused. I agree, it's not a Z-module and I shouldn't be able to get it as a quotient of Z-modules. It's part of why I'm so confused.

Comment: Damn, really? That makes sense, thanks for saving me then

Comment: The thing is, there *are* exactly three extensions in the category of groups, which is why I thought you were trying to make group extensions!

Comment: For the record, I was looking at Prop 1.1 in chapter 3, : $\text{Ext}_Z(Z_m, A) \simeq A/mA$ for A abelian and $Z_m$ cyclic.

Comment: It seems to me that you have the false expectation that $\operatorname{Ext}^1$ has a single element per isomorphism class of the (middle) group when, in fact, its elements represent equivalence classes of short exact sequences. Consider the following. For all primes $p$ we have $\operatorname{Ext}^1_{\Bbb{Z}}(\Bbb{Z}_p,\Bbb{Z}_{p^2})\simeq \Bbb{Z}_p$. But there are only two possible abelian groups that fit into the short exact sequence, the direct sum (= the neutral element of the $\operatorname{Ext}$-group) and $\Bbb{Z}_{p^3}$.

Comment: (cont'd) The catch is that the latter fits into $p-1$ pairwise non-equivalent short exact sequences. Eric Wofsey's answer (+1) adds to this, as does the question he linked to.

Comment: Another point is that your notation for the group presentation of $P$ is a mixture of additive and multiplicative notation. As a general rule, it is preferable to use additive notation only for abelian groups. Multiplicative notation can be used for either. For various reasons you sometimes need to change notation for a specific group, but you should never mix the two in this way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note first of all that the extensions classified by Ext are extensions within the category of abelian groups.  So, $P$ should definitely be abelian, and your description of it as a pushout is correct (but note that this is a pushout in the category of abelian groups, not in the category of all groups).

I'm not sure exactly what you mean when you talk about the homotopy class of $h^i$ (you talk about a morphism between complexes, but which two complexes are you talking about?).  In any case, though, your $h^2$ actually gives the same extension as $h^0$ (so, the trivial extension).  Indeed, two homomorphisms $3\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}_9$ give the same extension iff they differ by a homomorphism that can be extended to $\mathbb{Z}$.  In this case, $h^2-h^0=h^2$ can be extended to $\mathbb{Z}$ by having it map each $n$ to $n$ mod $9$.  You can see explicitly that the inclusion $i':\mathbb{Z}_9\to P$ splits for your extension by mapping $(a,b)\in \mathbb{Z}_9\oplus\mathbb{Z}$ to $a+b$ mod $9$ (this vanishes on $N$, and so is well-defined on $P$).

To get the third extension that really is different, you would instead want to take $h(3n)=2n$ mod $9$.  Since this $h$ does not extend to $\mathbb{Z}$ it gives a nontrivial extension, and it also gives a different extension than your $h^1$ does since $h-h^1=h^1$ does not extend to $\mathbb{Z}$.  Note though that the group $P$ you will get from this $h$ is actually isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{27}$.  So up to isomorphism there are only two possibilities for the group $P$, even though there are three different extensions.  This is because for two extensions to be equivalent, you need not just an isomorphism of the $P$'s but an isomorphism that is compatible with the short exact sequences.  See [Can two elements of an Ext group come from the same middle object of an SES?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3734520/can-two-elements-of-an-ext-group-come-from-the-same-middle-object-of-an-ses) for more discussion.

Comment: Ah I see. In retrospect that makes complete sense, (that Ext classifies SES and not the iso class of the middle module). Thanks for untangling me. Also, the morphism between complexes thing is just how MacLane presents it, he treats the top row in my diagram as a projective resolution (i.e. an exact, projective complex) and then one direction of the isomorphism between Ext and the homology of that complex is the construction I was following here, where you form the pushout (for higher Ext groups, you'd be filling in more modules)...

Comment: .. at which point, I'm assuming what you said about differing by a hom. that can be extended reduces to being homotopy equivalence or something, I'm planning to sort that out later.